# Validate ipn on Avanagate payment processor

Tags: python, python-3.x, avangate

I'm trying to validate the ipn from avangate, for this I need to validate the HASH. The documentation is here:
https://developer.avangate.com/Webhooks/Instant_Payment_Notification_(IPN)#Calculate_the_HASH_signature

From avangate on POST, I receive a QueryDict which contains the HASH parameter, I try to create a new md5 which needs to be equal with the md5 from QueryDict.

My code:

```
signature = data['HASH']
result = ''.encode('UTF-8')
for key, value in data.items():
    if key == 'HASH':
        continue
    else:
        if not str(value).strip():
            result += "0".encode('UTF-8')
        else:
            result += str(len(value)).encode('UTF-8') + value.encode('UTF-8')
 result_hash = hmac.HMAC(secret_key.encode('UTF-8'), result).hexdigest()
 print(signature == result_hash)
```

I tried a lot of things but I can't make it work. On Avangate I selected all the options on the tab `Notification details`

Comment: Python dictionaries are unordered; surely you need to concatenate the field data in a specific order to generate the correct hash.

Comment: This is also why I think, but they don't specify the order, I tried only with the keys in the example and is not working, I also tried with the data on request.body, which are url parrams and I splitted by '&' and is not working either. I lost like 7 hours on this

Comment: I only had a brief look at the linked page; I had to close it because the page stopped responding. All I can suggest is that you supply the keys in the same order as their PHP example code. The simple way to do that in Python is to store the keys in a tuple (or list), and then loop over that tuple to retrieve your `dict` values in the correct order.

Comment: BTW, you should mention which Python version you're using. I'm pretty sure your code will work correctly in Python 2 or 3, but it's always good to mention the version when doing stuff that involves Unicode or raw byte strings.

Comment: Python3.5, isnot python realted